# Return the action Selected in UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am new to Swift and iOS development.
I am trying to get sort method from ActionSheet.
Here's my code:

```
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sort", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Price: Low to High", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Latest", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Price: High to Low", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default , handler: nil))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I understand that I can mark some variable in handler...but is there any better way to get the selected option by the user?

I have read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertController/addAction

but still I can't find a solution.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

swift takes a new approach when dealing with alert views/action sheets. when you add an `UIAlertAction` to your `UIAlertController` there is a parameter called `handler`. this is the code (called closure), which will be called when user selects one of the actions on your action sheet.
the final code can look something like this

```
enum SortType {
    case PriceLowToHigh, Latest, PriceHighToLow
}

func sort(sortType: SortType) {
    //do your sorting here depending on type
}

var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sort", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Price: Low to High", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (_) -> Void in sort(SortType.PriceLowToHigh) } )

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Latest", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (_) -> Void in sort(SortType.Latest) } )

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Price: High to Low", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (_) -> Void in sort(SortType.PriceHighToLow) } )

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))]
```

you can (**and should**) read more about closures [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Comment: thanks @kap...I will try that...Can you please explain how to use the 'actions' variable ?

Comment: you are welcome. which variable are you referring to?

Comment: class UIAlertController : UIViewController {
var actions: [AnyObject] { get }
}
command-click UIAlertController...You can read the description of 'actions' on developer.apple.com

Comment: you don't have to use it at all. just add the actions and display the action sheet. when the user taps a button the relevant code will be called

Comment: I understand your solution...but as I am learning, I wanted to know the significance of the variable...Thanks!